# Unterminated object character in json android

Tags: android, json

i try replacing escape sequence and special character from  json but nothing seem to work ,

```
String reString=stringresponce.replaceAll("<", "").replaceAll("!", "").replaceAll("-", "").replaceAll("/", "").replaceAll(">", "").replaceAll("#", "").replaceAll("/\r", "").replaceAll("/\n", "").replaceAll("/\r/\n", "").replaceAll("/\r/\n", "");



  org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 325 of 
[{"business_id":17,"business_name":"SOMALI EDUCATION RESOURCE CENTER","business_address":"4337 Cleveland Avenue, Columbus, OH 43224, USA","business_google_long":"82.95385742","business_google_lat":"40.05750275","contact_no":"614 525 9083","contact_no2":null,"contact_no3":null,"business_website":"http:\\www.serc360.com\","sub_category_id":"25","category_id":"12","date_created":"20141127 14:24:45","business_description":"The mission of the Somali Education and Resource Center is to provide skills and literacy by expanding the knowledge of immigrants and refugees by teaching them the financial social and cultural skills that provide a foundation to attain selfsufficiency. We also offer the following services.\r\n\r\nFamily Literacy\r\nAfterSchool Program Activities\r\nYouth Training\r\nFinancial Literacy","subscriber_id":"23","images":[{"image_name":"bi\1417123343010serc1.png"},{"image_name":"bi\1417123433298serc4.jpg"},{"image_name":"bi\1417123485124serc2.JPG"}],"rating":"4","reviews":[],"business_hours":[{"bh_day":"Saturday","bh_start":"09:00 AM","bh_end":"5:00 PM"},{"bh_day":"Sunday","bh_start":"09:00 AM","bh_end":"5:00 PM"},{"bh_day":"Monday","bh_start":"09:00 AM","bh_end":"5:00 PM"},{"bh_day":"Tuesday","bh_start":"09:00 AM","bh_end":"5:00 PM"},{"bh_day":"Wednesday","bh_start":"09:00 AM","bh_end":"5:00 PM"},{"bh_day":"Thursday","bh_start":"09:00 AM","bh_end":"5:00 PM"},{"bh_day":"Friday","bh_start":"09:00 AM","bh_end":"5:00 PM"}],"prayerTimings":[]},{"business_id":18,"business_name":"SOMALI COMMUNITY RESETTLEMENT SERVICES INC","business_address":"2593 South Ferris Park Drive, Columbus, OH 43224, USA","business_google_long":"82.95046997","business_google_lat":"40.08499146","contact_no":" (507) 7210641","contact_no2":null,"contact_no3":null,"business_website":"http:\\somalcrs.wix.com\scrs","sub_category_id":"25","category_id":"12","date_created":"20141127 14:37:02","business_description":"SCRS Mission\r\n \r\nTo promote and advance the social well being and the welfare of its members by providing muchneeded community and resettlement services with ultimate goal of building vibrant community whose members can successfully settle and effectively integrate into the wider American Community. ","subscriber_id":"24","images":[],"rating":"4","reviews":[],"business_hours":[{"bh_day":"Saturday","bh_start":"12:00 PM","bh_end":"12:00 PM"},{"bh_day":"Sunday","bh_start":"12:00 PM","bh_end":"12:00 PM"},{"bh_day":"Monday","bh_start":"12:00 PM","bh_end":"12:00 PM"},{"bh_day":"Tuesday","bh_start":"12:00 PM","bh_end":"12:00 PM"},{"bh_day":"Wednesday","bh_start":"12:00 PM","bh_end":"12:00 PM"},{"bh_day":"Thursday","bh_start":"12:00 PM","bh_end":"12:00 PM"},{"bh_day":"Friday","bh_start":"12:00 PM","bh_end":"12:00 PM"}],"prayerTimings":[]}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is this : "http:\\www.serc360.com\" 
normally blackslashes are used to escape characters, so the last \ breaks your String, and normally, http addresses are formated like this : http://, and not http:\\ 
Hope it helps!